# How we can access kubernetes ingress controller IP using https?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-keyvault, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I have deployed application in **Azure Kubernetes (AKS)**. I have used ingress-controller for my POC. Previously I was using domain (saurabh.com). **I am able to access saurabh.com through https.**

Now what I want is that I want to access my application using **IP address with https**.

My ingress controller yaml files looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: saurabh-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
   - secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
   - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: saurabh-ui
            port:
              number: 4200
```

By doing this, **I am able to access my application using IP but its coming http not https**. Can someone please help me with this. I want to access my application IP through https.

**Note:** I have installed the certificates. When I am trying to access domain using saurabh.com, its coming with https.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried reproduce the issue in my environment and got the below results***

*Please use this [link to access the files](https://github.com/komali323/ingress.git)*

***I have created the namespace***

```
kubectl create namespace namespace_name
```

***Created the applications and deployed into the kubernetes***

```
kubectl apply -f filename.yaml
```

***To check the namespaces which are created and we can get the IP address using below command***

```
kubectl get svc -n namespace_name
```

*I have installed the helm chat for controller and deployed the ingress resource into the kubernetes*

***NOTE:*** *After installing the nginx controller we have to change  the Cluster IP to LoadBalancer.*

***Here I have enabled HTTPS in AKS using cert manager, it will automatically generate and configured***

***I have created the namespace for cert manager***

```
kubectl create namespace namespace_name
kubectl get svc namespace namespace_name
```

***I have installed the cert manager using helm using below command***

```
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
 --namespace cert-manager \
    --version v0.14.0 \
 --set installCRDs=true
```

[image]

***To check the cert manager namespace***

```
kubectl get pods --namespace cert-manager
```

[image]

***I have created the cluster issuer and deployed***

```
vi filename.yaml
kubectl apply --namespace app -f filename.yaml
```

***I have created and installed the TLS or SSL certificates***

```
kubectl apply --namespace app -f filename.yaml
```

***We can verify that the certificate is created or not using below command***

*Here it will show the certificate is created or not*

```
kubectl describe cert app-web-cert --namespace namespace_name
```

***Check the service using below command***

```
    kubectl get services -n app
```

***Test the app with HTTPS: https://hostname with IP address***

Here we can also check the certificates which we have added.

[image]

Comment: Hii @Komali Annem, thanks for your response. Seems like you are using hostname also with IP to access application. But my goal is to access application using public ip through https protocol.